# What effect does exposure to the elements (hot sun & rain) have on cars and motorcycles?

Tags: engine, overheating, safety, lubrication, india

**Place:** South India.
**Situation:** Parking in an open space with no shade, morning to evening.
**Temperature:** 30 to 40 degrees Celsius.

I have parked my car under the hot sun for a week, and I noticed there were squeaks whenever I braked, and even the engine sounded different. Even my neighbour says (without me bringing up the topic) he noticed problems with his car after repeatedly parking under the hot sun. I need to convince a person to install some kind of shades in the parking area, but without knowing exactly what is happening to the vehicle, I won't have any convincing points to present to him.

Whether it is a car or a bike, I assume the fuel evaporation would be quicker and all the other lubricating fluids in the vehicle would also be affected. A colleague even tells me her scooter does not start if rainwater enters it (hard to believe though). I also saw [this post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24354/headlights-come-on-by-themselves-when-car-sitting-in-sun) about headlights coming on spontaneously.

I saw this video about using [sun-shades](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWra2SE5Sf0), but they don't say anything about the bonnet. [Other websites](https://www.roblevine.com/damaging-effects-sun-can-car-besides-ruin-paint/) speak in a general way about 'the fluids', but offer no details. I am posting here because I want to know the specifics.